# Having different timers running for each item of gridview with a same page template without conflicts

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, timer

I hava two pages in flutter
First()
Seccond()
I have a GridView in first page and seccond page shows a timer
I go to seccond page with navigator.push() and pass the id of each item in gridview and I start the timer for one item in gridview.
The seccond page shows different ids for different based on the item with which I have navigated to Seccond page.
But when I start the timer for each item of the gridview and although I save timer states for each item on sharedPreferences, when I go back to first page and choose another item in gridview, the timers conflict and are basically same for each item.
How can I stop this conflict?
How will I be able to run a different timer for rach item simultaneously with same seccond page template (without the need to design a different page for each item in my gridview)?

I tried to save each timer to shared preferences and load the shared pref to each timer when loading the second page but it didnt work

Comment: It's almost impossible to help if you don't show the code.